# Spring cloud config client properties are not getting resolved

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix, spring-cloud-config

I am very new to the concept of Spring Cloud and Spring external configurations, in fact started yesterday itself.

I have created one Config Server picking the configurations from a local Git repository, one micro service which is also the config client and one Eureka driven service discovery server.

Below is the code that i have mostly borrowed from various resources across internet -

Config Server - application.yml:

```
server:
  port: 8888

spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          uri: file:///${user.home}/config-repo
```

Config Server - Main class (bootstrap)

```
@EnableConfigServer
@SpringBootApplication
public class CloudConfigServerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CloudConfigServerApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

config-repo is the local git repo on my machine and has got a .yml file with name of the config client application i.e. authmanager.yml

```
eureka:
    client:
        serviceUrl:
            defaultZone: http://127.0.0.1:8761/eureka/
        healthcheck:
            enabled: true
        lease:
            duration: 5
spring:
    application:
        data:   
            mongodb:
                host: localhost
                port: 27017
                database: edc_mc
logging:
    level:
        org.exampledriven.eureka.customer.shared.CustomerServiceFeignClient: FULL
```

Now after running the config server, below is the output of the end point http://localhost:8888/authmanager/default -

```
{"name":"authmanager","profiles":["default"],"label":"master","version":"0ca6ca7b4502b9bb6ce1bf8efeb25516682cf79a","propertySources":[{"name":"file:///C:\\Users\\username/config-repo/authmanager.yml","source":{"eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone":"http://127.0.0.1:8761/eureka/","eureka.client.healthcheck.enabled":true,"eureka.client.lease.duration":5,"spring.application.data.mongodb.host":"localhost","spring.application.data.mongodb.port":27017,"spring.application.data.mongodb.database":"db_name","logging.level.org.exampledriven.eureka.customer.shared.CustomerServiceFeignClient":"FULL"}}]}
```

Micro service + Config client code -

bootstrap.yml -

```
server:
  port: 9097

spring:
  application:
    name: authmanager
  cloud:
    config:
      uri: http://localhost:8888
```

Client - Main class (bootstrap) -

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@EnableWebMvc
public class CloudLoginManagerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CloudLoginManagerApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Controller class in the config client, where i want to use the configuration file properties -

```
@RefreshScope
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/auth")
public class MyController {

    @Value("${spring.application.data.mongodb.database}")
    String env_var;
```

Skipping rest of the code for clarity sake.

This is the error i am getting -

```
Could not resolve placeholder 'spring.application.data.mongodb.database' in string value "${spring.application.data.mongodb.database}"
```

Other properties like server.port is not giving issues.

I have also tried the Environment interface way, but thats returning null as well.

Any pointers please, i have almost reached dead end now.

Thanks,

AJ

Comment: For me its working. Check if you have any typo in your code.

Comment: Ok, sorry for replying late, this worked for me. some how the configuration parameter which i was using was incorrect. based on that i thought my cofnig is worng. Anyways thatnks a lot for responsding.

Comment: @aj1984can u please tell what exactly fixed he issue? Even I am facing the same problem

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To enable cloud config you have to add the `spring-cloud-starter-config` to your dependencies. You can verify by checking the /env (might need to add actuator) to see which properties are available.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Hi Jeff, sorry for replying late, this worked for me. some how the configuration parameter which i was using was incorrect. based on that i thought my cofnig is worng. Anyways thatnks a lot for responsding.

Comment: Hey Jeff, i again hit the same issue and finally the dependency you suggested actually helped. Thanks.

Comment: Simply to say that if you do not have the dependency included it will fail with out an error message being printed even with org.springframework being set to TRACE, many thanks Jeff for pointing this out

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I add the spring-cloud version in the properties section.

1 : Add spring cloud version:

```
<properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2021.0.1</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
```

2 : `dependencyManagement` below of the  `<dependencies>`

```
  <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

Answer (score 0):

1-if you using maven, add this dependency:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

2-if you using gradle, add this dependency:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-config'
}
```

3- refrech